# Batch file Nested for loop for identifying shares

Tags: windows, batch-file, network-shares

I have the following scenario

```
    @echo off
    for %%x in (
    machine1
    machine2
    machine3

for %%y in (
    A
    B
    C
    D
           )
              )

    do
    (
    echo machine is %%x

    \\%%x\%%y

    )
```

I am actually checking if the shares open

\\machine1\A , \\machine1\B, and so on..

Can you guys help me with the nest for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to loop through a bunch of computers, and on each computer loop through a bunch of drive letters to see if the drive is shared? If so, you're really close. You just need to use `IF EXIST` to check if the path you are building is shared.

```
@echo off
FOR %%x IN (machine1, machine2, machine3) DO (
    echo Checking shares on machine: %%x
    FOR %%y IN (A, B, C, D) DO (
        echo Testing share: \\%%x\%%y
        if exist \\%%x\%%y (echo Shared) else (echo Not Shared)
   )
)
```

Comment: I modified the code as you mentioned but i get  "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: Maybe enable delayed expansion? http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html Not sure. It works fine for me when I specify a machine on my network that has a network share. Do you have a known good path you can test with? eg `\\mickey\mouse"`?

Comment: The nested For DO is the issue , the moment I have the nested structure i get an error.

Comment: What version of Windows is this? What if you get rid of the extra parenthesis? eg `FOR %%x IN (machine....) DO FOR %%y IN (A....) DO IF EXIST \\%%x\%%y (ECHO Shared) ELSE (ECHO Not Shared)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for %%x in ( "machine1", "machine2", "machine3" ) do (
    echo machine is %%x
    for %%y in ( "A", "B", "C", "D" ) do (
        echo share is \\%%x\%%y
    )
)
```